# Get all attribs from element and his child using Python

Tags: python, xml, nested, nodes

I'm trying to perform some kind of XMLs (now with xml.etree.ElementTree) to JSON (and to study Python, using it in my real noncritical tasks). Example of XML:

```
<ExportData name="ExportData" hwId="0120">
  <input name="Ethernet" type="Ethernet" id="100" numTs="0" ... />
  <input name="ASI" type="ASI" id="0" numTs="1" ... >
    <setup name="ASI Input 1" id="1" description="ASI" tsSync="no" currentlyMonitored="true" ... />
  </input>
  <input name="FD1" type="FD" id="1" numTs="1" ... >
    <setup name="NewPreset1" id="1" description="642 MHz" ... />
  </input>
  <input name="FD2" type="FD" id="2" numTs="0" ... />
</ExportData>
```

My current task is: for all of "input" nodes, who have child with name "setup", get common (concatenated) names and ids (for example above: name="ASI:ASI Input 1" and id="0:1"), then get all attributes of both nodes - current and child, excepting name and id (for example above: numTs, description, tsSync, ...)

I have a lot of "googled" examples of code, based on different principals (xpaths, if/for root.childNodes, etc), and now I can extract attributes from one of parental or child node (in different ways)), but I steel can not to get all of them..

Then, I need to print parsed data in JSON like this:

```
{
 "data":[
  { "{#INPUTID}":"0:1", "{#INPUTNAME}":"ASI:ASI Input 1", "{#INPUTPARAM}":"numTs"       },
  { "{#INPUTID}":"0:1", "{#INPUTNAME}":"ASI:ASI Input 1", "{#INPUTPARAM}":"tsSync"      },
  { "{#INPUTID}":"1:1", "{#INPUTNAME}":"FD1:NewPreset1", "{#INPUTPARAM}":"description" } 
  ...
 ]
}
```

(JSON is humanreadable, it is will be enough for any valid JSON..)

How can I solve my task in gracefull python-way? (with neat algorithm and correct errors and exceptions handling?). Thanks beforehand!

**UPD** My progress:

```
ExportData = ET.fromstring(xml)

# First, create empty Output Dict by Template
# It will be implemented with needet data later
outData = { 'data': [] }

# Then I create 2 Dicts, for node & subnode, if subnode consists 
# necessery pattern
# All further manipulations will bi done with this Dicts
for input in ExportData.findall('input'):
  if input.find('tuningSetup') is not None:
    inputParams = input.attrib
    setupParams = input.find('tuningSetup').attrib
    inputId = inputParams['id'] + ':' + setupParams['id']
    inputName = inputParams['name'] + ':' + setupParams['name']
    del inputParams['name'], inputParams['id'] #, inputParams['numTs']
    del setupParams['name'], setupParams['id'] #, setupParams['numTs']
    commonParams = dict(inputParams.items() + setupParams.items())
    for param, value in commonParams.iteritems():
      outData['data'].append({ '{#INPUTID}': inputId, '{#INPUTNAME}': inputName, '{#INPUTPARAM}': param}
)

# Finally, dumping data to json
print json.dumps(outData, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

Comment: Are you missing a few commas in your JSON?

Comment: I understand that my task is too complex to solve it in one comment, so I hope for advices and working exaples of code from community. (I dont want to bee leecher))

Comment: About commas - yes, I missed them, thank you

Comment: I edited the commas in for you, but in the future, you can do it yourself by clicking the little `edit` button right beneath the tags on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little code to get you started:

```
s = """<ExportData name="ExportData" hwId="0120">
  <input name="Ethernet" type="Ethernet" id="100" numTs="0" />
  <input name="ASI" type="ASI" id="0" numTs="1" >
    <setup name="ASI Input 1" id="1" description="ASI" tsSync="no" currentlyMonitored="true" />
  </input>
  <input name="FD1" type="FD" id="1" numTs="1" >
    <setup name="NewPreset1" id="1" description="642 MHz" />
  </input>
  <input name="FD2" type="FD" id="2" numTs="0" />
</ExportData>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(s)
for node in tree.iter('input'):
  child = next((c for c in node if c.tag == 'setup'), None)
  if child is None: 
    continue
  else:
    print node, child
```

This results in the following output:

```
<Element 'input' at 0x1047541d0> <Element 'setup' at 0x104754210>
<Element 'input' at 0x104754250> <Element 'setup' at 0x104754290>
```

This gets you the parent and the child nodes.  From there, you can easily get their attributes using `node.attrib` and `child.attrib`.  Then it just becomes a matter of pulling the attributes that you want to combine together formatting the rest.

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
copypasted code here`

causes

`    for node in tree.iter('input'):
  AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'
`

Comment: @user2583148 -- What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6.6, there is no `iter` in it, but..

mgilson, thanks for `child is None`, I found description of this "gotcha" in 'Dive Into Python 3, Chapter 12'

I'm steel can not fully understanding magic of `child = next((c for c in node if c.tag == 'setup'), None)`, so I use light version of it, (see *upd* in topic) and now I can get values of necessary attributes of node and childrens!..

Comment: as far as I understand, xml-attributes are Dictonaries in terms of Python, and now I smoke how to exclude this two (name + id)..

Comment: @user2583148 -- Just create a new dict:  `d = dict(node.attrib)` and then remove the key you don't want:  `del d['name']` or you could pop out the value:  `name = d.pop('name')`